# can Eclipse Che be used for traditional monolithic application development? Application that does not make use of Docker

Tags: eclipse, web, ide, eclipse-che

Can **Eclipse Che** be used for traditional monolithic application development? An application that does not make use of Docker. If possible is it a good decision to move to Eclipse Che from a desktop Eclipse? Does Che provide all kind of plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely - Che uses Docker under the hood as a way to create replicable and portable environments, but the code that's edited in Che is pushed to the repo like any other. So if you have a build system / CI setup to pull those changes from the repo and deploy forward a monolithic app that will all still work.

To set it up you'll need to build out a Dockerfile that matches your runtime. You can find examples of most environments on [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/) and there are just a [couple of things you need to add](https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/recipes) to make the container "Che-ready."

Comment: "couple of things you need to add " is a dead link